# T-SQL: Move data to next row depending on field value

Tags: sql-server, loops, t-sql

I have a scenario in which customers place orders all days per week (Monday to Sunday). However, the warehouse does not proceed orders on saturdays/sundays. I have a flag which tells me whether or not a day is a working day (=1) or not (=0). Also I have the placed orders per day. Now, the warehouse wants to see the aggregated weekends value on top of that from a monday. This is an excerpt of the original selection (the result is an cte-aggregate from the fact-table):

```
day      weekday    qty
01.12.2016  1      4551
02.12.2016  1      4283
03.12.2016  0      3925
04.12.2016  0      4918
05.12.2016  1      4905
06.12.2016  1      4831
07.12.2016  1      10920
08.12.2016  1      2603
09.12.2016  1      2578
10.12.2016  0      2314
11.12.2016  0      2932
12.12.2016  1      3491
```

On 5.12. I would like to have T-SQL do the following calculation beforehand:

1. 03.12.: weekday = 0 -> move 3925 to next row and add it to value of 04.12. Make 03.12. qty = 0
2. 04.12.: weekday = 0 -> move (3925+4918=8843) to next row and add it to value of 05.12. Make 04.12. qty=0
3. 05.12.: weekday = 1 -> move nothing to next day but just "collect" the qty of previous days: qty = 8843+4905=13748

The result would look like this:

```
  day        weekday    qty
    01.12.2016  1      4551
    02.12.2016  1      4283
    03.12.2016  0      0
    04.12.2016  0      0
    05.12.2016  1      13748
    06.12.2016  1      4831
```

Restrictions: I have no write-data-rights on that database hence no temporary tables are possible.

Comment: What is the version of sql-server?

Comment: Version 11.0.6544.0 is installed

Comment: Besides, I have been granted rights to use temporary tables as well..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Variant 1:** You can create view from agregated subqry.

```
select 
    WorkDay, 
    sum (qty) SumQty, 
    sum (case when [weekday] = 1 then qty end) SumQtyOnlyWorkDay, 
    sum (case when [weekday] = 0 then qty end) SumQtyOnlyFreeDay
from (
    select *, 
        [day] WorkDay
    from SrcTable t
    where [weekday] = 1
    union all
    select *, 
        (select top 1 [day] from @T d where d.[day] > t.[day] and d.[weekday] = 1 order by [day] asc) descendantWorkDay
    from SrcTable t
    where [weekday] = 0) m
group by WorkDay
```

Solution only get next first working day for free days. It could be one qry like:

**Variant 2:**

```
select *, 
    isnull((
        select top 1 [day] 
        from SrcTable d 
        where d.[day] > t.[day] 
           and d.[weekday] = 1 
           and t.[weekday] = 0 
        order by [day] asc), [day]) descendantWorkDay
from SrcTable t
```

With index on [day] field.

Try avoid CTE when it's not necessary - it's complicated to make optimalized qry (for example with using ranking function in first statement you force execution plan and next qry cannot benefit from index). CTE is commonly used for recursion or full table joins or complicated views.

Comment: ok, need the rest of the working day to figure out what's happening here :-) thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your sql server version is 2012 or later, you can use this 2 step process.

**Note:** This solution is based on a maximum of 2 days in a row where the `day` column is marked as `0`. It will not work for longer periods if `0` such as long weekends.

First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    day date,
    weekday bit,
    qty int
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES

('01.12.2016', 1, 4551),
('02.12.2016', 1, 4283),
('03.12.2016', 0, 3925),
('04.12.2016', 0, 4918),
('05.12.2016', 1, 4905),
('06.12.2016', 1, 4831),
('07.12.2016', 1, 10920),
('08.12.2016', 1, 2603),
('09.12.2016', 1, 2578),
('10.12.2016', 0, 2314),
('11.12.2016', 0, 2932),
('12.12.2016', 1, 3491)
```

Then use a couple of [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)s with [`case`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) and [`lag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) to calculate the quantity. The first will create the calculated quantity for the second day of the weekend and the second one for the first day of the week.

```
;WITH CTE1 AS
(
    SELECT  day, 
            weekday, 
            qty,
            CASE WHEN weekday = 0 AND LAG(weekday) OVER (ORDER BY day) = 0 THEN 
                qty + LAG(qty) OVER (ORDER BY day) 
            ELSE 
                qty 
            END As calculated_qty
    FROM @T
), CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT  day, 
            weekday, 
            qty,
            CASE WHEN weekday = 1 AND LAG(weekday) OVER (ORDER BY day) = 0 THEN 
                calculated_qty + LAG(calculated_qty) OVER (ORDER BY day) 
            ELSE 
                CASE WHEN weekday = 0 THEN 0 ELSE qty END
            END As calculated_qty
    FROM CTE1
)

SELECT *
FROM CTE2
```

Results:

```
day                     weekday qty     calculated_qty
12.01.2016 00:00:00     True    4551    4551
12.02.2016 00:00:00     True    4283    4283
12.03.2016 00:00:00     False   3925    0
12.04.2016 00:00:00     False   4918    0
12.05.2016 00:00:00     True    4905    13748
12.06.2016 00:00:00     True    4831    4831
12.07.2016 00:00:00     True    10920   10920
12.08.2016 00:00:00     True    2603    2603
12.09.2016 00:00:00     True    2578    2578
12.10.2016 00:00:00     False   2314    0
12.11.2016 00:00:00     False   2932    0
12.12.2016 00:00:00     True    3491    8737
```

Comment: Hi, I'll try that. Christmas time has usually 3 or more weekdays = 0. MSSQL 2014 is installed.

Comment: Hence my **note** at the top of the answer. This will not work for weekends longer then 2 days.

Comment: I have been granted rights to use temporary tables. If I use some version of CTE1 and loop it through until no sum(qty) where weekday = 0 equals 0? Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have been granted rights to use temp tables. This should work for any number of non work days. It loops through the table and uses an if statement to drop the [false] days to the next [true] day
I used table create statements Zohar posted.
(This is one of my first posts so I hope I post this correctly)

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
xday date,
xweekday bit,
qty int
)
DECLARE @result AS TABLE -- table to store results
(
xday date,
xweekday bit,
qty int
)
INSERT INTO @T VALUES

('12/01/2016', 1, 4551),
('12/02/2016', 1, 4283),
('12/03/2016', 0, 3925),
('12/04/2016', 0, 4918),
('12/05/2016', 1, 4905),
('12/06/2016', 1, 4831),
('12/07/2016', 1, 10920),
('12/08/2016', 1, 2603),
('12/09/2016', 1, 2578),
('12/10/2016', 0, 2314),
('12/11/2016', 0, 2932),
('12/12/2016', 1, 3491)

declare @xday date
declare @xweekday bit
declare @qty int
declare @sumqty int = 0 -- temp column to hold [false day] qty values

while exists (select * from @T) -- loop through table
begin
select top 1 @xday = xday, @xweekday = xweekday,@qty=qty from @T
                   order by xday asc
set @sumqty = @sumqty + @qty
if (@xweekday = 1)   -- loop though holidays sum qty only
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @result values (@xday,@xweekday,@sumqty)
    set @sumqty = 0
END
else 
begin
INSERT INTO @result values (@xday,@xweekday,0)
end
delete @T
where xday = @xday

end

select * from @result

should produce this.
xday    xweekday    qty
2016-12-01  1   4551
2016-12-02  1   4283
2016-12-03  0   0
2016-12-04  0   0
2016-12-05  1   13748
2016-12-06  1   4831
2016-12-07  1   10920
2016-12-08  1   2603
2016-12-09  1   2578
2016-12-10  0   0
2016-12-11  0   0
2016-12-12  1   8737
```